# É possível comentar um arquivo JSON?

Tags: json

Posso comentar um arquivo JSON? Se sim, como?

Comment: É famosa. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244777/can-i-comment-a-json-file

Comment: se salvar seu arquivo como jsonc é possível fazer comentários.

Comment: @tamires vale lembrar que para usar **JSONC** será preciso de recursos extras na maioria das linguagens, é provável que nativamente não irão interpretar. Alguns exemplos que falham: Python https://ideone.com/duLejU; PHP https://ideone.com/9VPSb5, então provavelmente para a maioria das linguagens terá que instalar terceiros

Comment: _"se salvar seu arquivo como jsonc é possível fazer comentários"_ **Sim, mas aí não funciona mais!** JSONC não é compatível com os parsers de JSON, e não funciona nos lugares onde o esperado é JSON.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Não. Não é possível comentar em JSON.

Comment: Eu tinha dado +1, apesar da prolixidade (um simples "não" bastaria :P), mas estou quase retirando... XML também guarda dados, mas ele dá suporte a comentários. Em tempo: eu acho muito bom JSON não permitir comentários, torna seu *parsing* simples e rápido, mas o fato de ser um formato de dados não exclui a possibilidade de suportar comentários.

Comment: @mgibsonbr é que eu me senti meio estranho ao responder apenas com a primeira frase, daí eu resolvi adicionar uma explicação do por quê que não faz sentido. Mas você tem razão, apesar de não fazer sentido pode-se comentar no XML, o que tornaria minha segunda frase incorreta :/

Comment: Eu sei, comentei em tom de brincadeira mesmo, além do que o sistema não deixaria uma resposta (ou mesmo um comentário) só com 3 letras... :) Quanto ao XML, pode-se dizer que os comentários são meta-dados, assim como o DTD e possivelmente outras coisas que eu nem conheço. Um JSON "semântico" poderia ter comentários, só que esses comentários teriam a mesma sintaxe dos outros dados (mas espero que isso não aconteça, JSON é *tão bom* simples do jeito que está!).

Comment: De todo modo, espero não ter causado mal-estar, seria melhor remover meus comentários?

Comment: Não precisa remover não, seus comentários são mais informativos que minha resposta, rsrs.. mas te digo que fiquei mais confuso do que estava antes. Acho que vou deixá-la do jeito que está, pois ela está simples assim como o JSON :)

Comment: Eu preferia o prolixo. Por que será? :P

Answer (score 20):

O padrão ECMA-404, que especifica o padrão JSON, não faz nenhum provisionamento para comentários.

Em casos onde comentários são estritamente necessários, *post-parsers* podem ser implementados para manipular o *payload* de maneira a eliminar qualquer conteúdo extra e manter a saída compatível com eventuais serviços consumidores. Porém não existe nenhum padrão estabelecido.

Fontes:

- http://json.org/
- http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf

Answer (score 10):

Não. Ele foi feito para não conter comentários, ele é somente uma estrutura de dados formatado como objeto.

**NOTA** caso seja necessário mesmo algum tipo de comentário, você pode inserir mais um campo dentro do seu objeto chamado `comment`ou algo do tipo...

Answer (score 5):

A especificação não permite, mas se você já tiver vendido sua alma para o diabo e alguém estiver apontando uma arma para a sua cabeça, você pode aplicar uma gambiarra.

Para um *parser* que não obtenha o JSON através de *streaming*, se uma mesma chave for declarada mais de uma vez, o valor que vai valer no final das contas é o que aparecer por último. Então, para comentar uma chave, crie outra chave de mesmo nome acima dela. Assim:

```
{
    "pessoa": "A pessoa a quem este arquivo se refere",
    "pessoa": {
        "nome": "O nome da pessoa",
        "nome": "John Doe"
    }
}
```

Apenas enfatizando o que eu já falei antes, mas com outras palavras: se você fizer isso acima você resolve um problema agora, mas você vai direto para o inferno logo depois.

Tirei essa ideia do post mais controverso do SOen até hoje:

[Can comments be used in JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18018493/2263584)